# logback-spring.xmlの設定で、0KB（出力なし）の場合、ファイル生成を行わないようにしたい

Tags: java, spring

現在、メインログとエラーログで生成ファイルを分けており、エラーログにはERRORレベルのログ出力しかしないように、フィルタリングをかけております。

ただ、処理が正常終了した場合でも、エラーログファイルが0KBで作成されてしまいます。

logback-spring.xmlの設定で、0KBの時はファイル生成を行わないように設定する事が可能でしょうか？？

Comment: 同様の質問が[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18910869/4506703)にありました。こちらでは、実際に必要になってからファイルをオープンするような`FileAppender`を自前で用意しているようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげで解決いたしました。